# Why would servicestack return the default html view rather then my markdown?

Tags: servicestack

I have a servicestack running at http://example.com/api.ashx
I setup have a response filter force a specific type of dto content to html and set its templateName property to "RulesView.md".
But I get the servicestack default json report view sent to the client not my mark down.  I have a views folder with a RulesView.md file. I am using version 3.7.9 if that is important.  Is there something I need to configure?

Answer (score 0):

If it returns the default json report than your request find a didn't match for the existing Markdown page:

Note: The TemplateName shouldn't contain the `.md` extension, try `RulesView` instead.

From: http://www.servicestack.net/docs/markdown/markdown-features

The resolution order ServiceStack's uses to resolve the appropriate Markdown template to use for rendering HTML output is:

1. If the Web Service specifies a template (via a customized IHttpResult.TemplateName response) - then a View with that name.
2. A view with the same name as the Response DTO, looking first in /Views then in /Views/Shared
3. A view with the same name as the Request DTO, looking first in /Views then in /Views/Shared

Comment: My responseDto is a HttpResult.  When I set the TemplateName property does servicestack look in the views folder?  It was not clear in the docs.

Comment: It looks at /Views and /Views/Shared

Comment: Is there any logging I could enable that might give me some insight into my misconfiguration?

Comment: You can start a relationship with the source and put a break-point on https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.EndPoints/Formats/MarkdownFormat.cs#L216 :)

Answer (score 0):

If you return HttpResult from your handler servicestack will not use the TemplateName property with markdown when writing to the response stream.  You have to set the HttpResult.Response to an IHttpResult( you cannot use HttpResult because it also implements IStreamWriter which writes the Response property to the http response stream). This means that when returning HttpResult you have to name your markdown page with the class name in the Response property.  Lastly it looks like when servicestack compiles a view it will not include files that had a syntax error.

In my case I had

```
@foreach p in products
-@p.Name
```

where I needed

```
@foreach p in Model.products{
- @p.Name
}
```